# iOS How to post UIImage and NSSrting to php script same post

Tags: php, ios

I would like to know if someone can give an example in code on how to post a uiiiamge and string parameters to a server at once. I know how to send string parameters but i dont know how to do both in the same post method.Can someone please demonstrate and explain.THANKS

Comment: Look into working with a POST that supports multipart/form-data.

Comment: thanks..and most of my questions never get answered or the answers are extremley vague..so posting in a multipart/form data will allow me to send these parameters to php in a body? in php how do i retrieve whats in the body post? $_POST??

Comment: A quick Google search should help you find a standard way to process multipart/form-data POSTS in PHP. A similar quick search should give you plenty of sample Objective-C code for creating such a post. Once setup, you can support sending any number of values, including image data, in a single post.

Comment: You can use ASIHTTPRequest or MKNetwork. :)

Comment: I update my last answer to your original post with an example from code I use to submit multipart form data from my app to a php page. Hopefully that helps you.